# How to implement OCR on google app engine? [java/python]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

How can i implement OCR on google app engine? I already googled and found out, i need pure python code to run on that environment. Is there any pure python library?

Answer (score 2):

App Engine is not limited to pure python code anymore. Just set up your own API for OCR using [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/). You can use any library you want. Note that Managed VMs are still in early beta, but you can start to build something with it already.